# Do exceptions in constructor imply their specialization?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I am working on a code looking like :

```cpp
Foo myFoo; // invalid object (not initialized to be usable)

if (TryCreateFooObject(arg, myFoo))  // myFoo is passed as not const pointer, and next potentially initialized
{
    // 20 lines of codes, some of them using myFoo
}
else
{
    logger.Error(...);
}
```

The success of `TryCreateFooObject()` depends on `args`.
Note the validity checking of `args` is made in the base class of `Foo`. `args` is an `int64`, splitted, and each component is checked. That may throw an exception, but less related to the context. Anyway, these exceptions will never be thrown, because the `Try` functions are always called before tempting to create the object.

So, instead of using that `TryCreateFooObject()` function, I'd want to throw an exception from the `Foo` constructor if this object cannot be created. But then, I don't know how to deal the business :

1. If I replace the `if` by a `try`, what should I throw and catch ? If I use a generic exception, I could catch any other exception thrown from the other 20 lines of code. But the only error to swallow is the one related to the `Foo` creation. Else, I could code a specialized exception. But would it mean I should code a specialized exception for each constructor throwing an exception ?
2. I could do a local `try`/`catch` around the `Foo` object instanciation, but it implies the object must be referencable outside this `try`/`catch`. So that means a default constructor (as today, but it is then a not initialized object), or using a pointer initially to `nullptr`, and addind a `if` for the 20 other lines of codes.

What should I do ? Thanks.

EDIT:

3. I could use a pointer :

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Foo> myFoo;

try
{
    myFoo = std::make_unique<Foo>(args);
}
catch (std::bad_alloc&)
{
    throw;
}
catch (...)
{
    logger.Error(...);
}

// 20 lines of codes, some of them using myFoo
```

Comment: the question is unclear. If you want to handle exceptions seperately from excpetions in the other 20 lines of code then simply `try` to create the object, `catch` potential excpetions, if there is none then `try` to do the other 20 lines of code

Comment: I do not want catch any exception potentially thrown by the 20 other lines.
You suggest me to use the 2nd proposal, but then, I sould use a default constructor or a pointer. You're OK with that ?

Comment: You're making the beginner mistake of believing you must have a dedicated `try`/`catch` around every operation that may throw, and keep other code out of the `try`/`catch` block.   Instead, in the body of the `try`/`catch` place both the object construction AND all the 20 lines of code that use the object.  If an exception is thrown while constructing the object, the code which uses the object will not be executed.

Comment: @Peter I know, but if I use a generic exception type, and the object construction is successful, the exception thrown by the other 20 lines of codes will also be catched. They were not in the original code.

Comment: If one set of exceptions are potentially thrown when constructing the object, and another set in code which uses the object, then you can have multiple `catch` blocks.  If you have the *same* exception potentially thrown for different reasons (e.g. when constructing an object, and later when using it) but need to resolve why each exception is thrown, then that's something you've chosen to do - probably better to redesign your error handling strategy than to slavishly stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. Maybe you simplified the code so much that the problem is gone. Anyhow, if you want to catch the exception from the constructor separate from other exceptions then simply do this:

```
Foo myFoo; // invalid object (not initialized to be usable)

try {
    TryCreateFooObject(arg,myFoo);
} catch (...) {
    // handle excpetion from creating the object
    // ...
    // and either rethrow or return, because the following code needs the object
    return;
}        
// now you can use myFoo
// 20 lines of codes, some of them using myFoo
```

Of course it would be better if the constructor creates an object in a valid state, because thats what constructors are supposed to do. If you want to write the code like this:

```
try { 
    Foo myFoo;
    // 20 lines of codes, some of them using myFoo
} catch(...) {
    logger.Error(...);
}
```

Then yes, one way to distinguish the exception thrown in the constructor from other exceptions is to use a custom type of exception. `std::runtime_error` comes in handy here, it is meant to be used as base class for excpetion that have a message.

Comment: 1st proposal : I don't want to use `TryCreateFooObject()`. Maybe you oversaw that, and that could explain why you don't see the problem. :)  
 
2nd proposal : Yes, so the the decision to make a specific exception is based on a specific usage. :( Hence the question asked in the subject.